# ERROR: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must not be called in a subtransaction in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am facing the following issue when I try to dump a database in YugabyteDB 2.13.0.1:

```
[yuga@yugadb-tserver1 ~]$ ./yugabyte-2.13.0.1/postgres/bin/ysql_dump -d ehrbase > ./backups/ehrbase_100.sql
ysql_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must not be called in a subtransaction
ysql_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE, READ ONLY, DEFERRABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar error can be seen in https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/11630 and is the same issue, there is a fix that will come in the immediate next 2.13.* release. The fix is already done, just not yet released.